# grafana TLS version configuration

Tags: grafana, grafana-api

Grafana version: 2.6.0

Grafana with default installation configs has got the SSL TLS versions 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2 enabled.

Is there any configuration with grafana just to enable grafana HTTPS port 3000 to support only TLS 1.2?

(Just to give more context, KAFKA has a config called ssl.enabled.protocols. With this we have option to set TLS version only TLSv1.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - especially with your old Grafana version. There was PR to customize TLS configuration, but hardcoded TLS config was merged at the end - https://github.com/grafana/grafana/pull/7347 => you need to use reverse proxy in front of Grafana to customize TLS.